# JDBC connection default autoCommit behavior

Tags: oracle, jdbc, autocommit

I'm working with JDBC to connect to Oracle. I tested `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` vs `connection.setAutoCommit(true)` and the results were as expected.

While by default connection is supposed to work as if `autoCommit(true)` [correct me if I'm wrong], but none of the records are being inserted till `connection.commit()` was called. Any advice regarding default behaviour?

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO MONITOR (number, name,value) VALUES (?,?,?)";

conn = connection; //connection  details avoided
preparedStmtInsert = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
preparedStmtInsert.execute();

conn.commit();
```

Comment: Can you show the code you actually used where it didn't work. Autocommit only occurs after the statement has been executed.

Comment: Are you doing anything in the `connection details avoided` section that does anything to affect the autocommit settings?

Comment: You didn't post the most interesting part - the code that creates a connection ;)

Comment: No. It just has url,passwords details thats it.(other database setting are not open to me)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [Oracle JDBC documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html):

> When a connection is created, it is in auto-commit mode. This means
>   that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is
>   automatically committed right after it is executed. (To be more
>   precise, **the default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is
>   completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all
>   of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved**. In almost
>   all cases, however, a statement is completed, and therefore committed,
>   right after it is executed.)

The other thing is - you ommitted connection creation details, so I'm just guessing - if you are using some frameworks, or acquiring a connection from a datasource or connection pool, the `autocommit` may be turned `off` by those frameworks/pools/datasources - the solution is to never trust in default settings ;-)

Comment: so should i take it as default may not be same as autocommit true in all cases. [something like default vs public in java]?

Comment: Defaults should be the same (autocommit=true) because that is what JDBC spec says. However, JDBC spec does not apply to frameworks, connection pools and datasources. For example, when defining a datasource in JBoss you can explicitely set autocommit to false in the datasource XML file, and the connections you will obtain from a pool will have it turned off by default.