# Spring Boot JDBC is constantly changing autocommit mode

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

Our Spring Boot application is changing constantly MySQL autocommit mode even with no activity within it. I mean, no endpoint calls, no runnable running, nothing using the application but it seems Spring Boot is doing something with MySQL because I see a lot of "SET autocommit=1" or "SET autocommit=0".

We manage a connection pool from the properties file. I tried to force auto-commit to true and false from properties but it did not work.

Our connections pool properties are the following:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=120
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=0
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=34000
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=55000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-interval=34000
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

Do you know why Spring Boot is making these autocommit queries with no one using the application?

Comment: When starting a tx auto commit is disabled. You are firing a lot of queries due to your validation query. I would stpo using the Tomcat connection pool and use the default HikariCP instead without a validation query.

Comment: How often do you mean by "constantly changing"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69695930/175554 may explain the situation.

Comment: @TheImpaler about 5500 times per second

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to start using HikariCP instead of TomcatCP and disabling validation query but nothing has changed about database CPU